# Google Sheet formula to check all rows and bring a third value

Tags: google-sheets, formula, vlookup

I'm trying to come up with a formula to look through two columns of data, which have most of the same cell values, just in different order, (Order Number and Order Number 2), to put the corresponding Event Value in the "Matched Event Value" cell.

So for instance, in row 1, N2 and O2 have the same value, "Order 1", so Q2 would populate with "123".

I've tried different versions of IF= and VLOOKUP=, but I haven't figured it out.[image]

Comment: How would that work out?, IF N2 and O2 match, then it repeats value from P2 in O2?, What would happen if they don't match?

Comment: What result do you expect for row 3 and 4?

Comment: I worded the question poorly. I'd like the formula to look through both N and O rows and bring the P value into Q. If it isn't a match, then it can be 0 for the value

Comment: Are you going to apply this formula to all rows in column **N**  & **O**? Or apply to a specific range of rows only?

Answer (score 0):

a bit unclear on the scope\expected output but you may try this in cell `Q1` cell:

```
={"Matched Event Value";INDEX(IF(LEN(N2:N)+LEN(O2:O),IF(EQ(N2:N,O2:O),P2:P,0),))}
```

- 

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In cell Q2 try adding this:

```
=IF(N2=O2,P2,0)
```

After that extend the formula to the lower cells.